# Is there a way to set an Android App's Bluetooth To Output As A Keyboard-Mice Data Type In Android Dev Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth

For a project, we are having an Android app send signals to a laptop to cause an action via Bluetooth, and with our program specifications, we need the app to output in some form of a Keyboard-Mice data type for the program to properly read it.

We do not have extensive experience in Android Developer Studio, so there may be something we are overlooking.

We have looked online at Android Developer Guides & elsewhere on the Internet to find a viable way for our app to send a Bluetooth output with data, and were unable to find anything. So far the best spot we found was through a Bluetooth Chat-Bot style connection.

Comment: I do not know what you mean with "Keyboard-Mice data type", anyway, mind that data are transferred as bytes, so it is just a matter of "sending the right bytes" on the bluetooth socket. (Not to self-promote) I have made a similar project (commanding the execution of scripts on the computer from an Android app using BLE) some time ago in [this](https://github.com/lorenzofelletti/ble_script_runner) repo. I hope it may help you.